# CLR library compiles but C# call returns error CS0103 even with existing compiled metadata

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr

I have a Visual Studio Solution with a Class Library (C#) and a CLR Class Library (C++). The CLR class library builds properly and it as simple as, for the header file:

```
public ref class CLRClass
{
public:
    static void CLRMethod();
};
```

The cpp implements just an empty *CLRMethod*. In the C# library I added a reference to the CLR project and I am just calling the CLR method:

```
CLRClass.CLRMethod();
```

The C# library does not build, returns error:

> error CS0103: The name 'CLRClass' does not exist in the current context

But surprisingly if I F12 on the *CLRClass* in Visual Studio it does bring me to the correct metadata of the compile file in the dll, showing that the CLR library is correctly compiled and accessible:

```
public class CLRClass
{
  public CLRClass();

  public static void CLRMethod();
}
```

I don't understand how the metadata is accessible but when compiling the C# library I get the CR0103 error, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Show the relevant part of the .csproj. It may have to do with the way you import the C++ reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was a .Net Framework problem, the libraries were targeting different frameworks, probably with the .csproj we have reached the same conclusion, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of C# .Net Target Framework Version. Notice that you have this warning in your reference:
[image: Warning in CLRLibrary that contains the CLRClass]

This is because the C# Class Library targets a Framework version that is older (4.7.1) than the one that the C++/CLI framework (4.8). Just retarget your C++ library.